# How can one integrate Angular4+ Spring MVC + Hibernate without maven?

Tags: angular, spring

How can we configure project with Spring and Angular without maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of the other build tools: Ant + Ivy, Gradle, SBT, Buildr etc.

Or download the necessary jars yourself. 
how to deploy Angular: https://angular.io/guide/deployment